# Risk Management in Pinescript, store old values

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i want to test a risk management idea in pinescript

If my last trade was a loss/stop loss, do not trade the next entry signal (trigger).

My triggers are:

`entry_long` -- if entry_long == true, open long position.

`entry_short` -- if entry_short == true, open short position.

There is another detail.

I want the system to recognize a "possible loss", without even opening the trade.

For ease of understanding, the image below represents the strategy opening trades abruptly, WITHOUT any risk management.

In the example below, with management, what would happen:

The 3rd trade would not happen due to the rule presented above, but despite the fact that it did not result in a loss in the strategy, because the trade would not be opened, IF it were opened, it would be a loss TOO.

So the 4th trade would not be opened either, because the last hypothetical trade is also a loss.

Obs: So I would always have to check the last time my triggers returned true, and store the value of these variables to be used later. I tried it, but I didn't get completely accurate results.

Consequently the 5th would not be opened either, because the last hypothetical trade is also a loss.

[image]

Thanks for you attention :)

Comment: With the your strategy source code (or simplified example) it will be simpler to give advice.

Comment: My strategy has many lines of code, but what I want to convey here would work in any type of strategy.

Example:
Trigger/Entry: RSI < 30, entry long
Exit: RSI > 50, close long trade.

Imagine that this strategy matches the print of the image above, were the performance of your strategy (5 trigger/entries).

Now, what I want.
Follow the explanation along with the image above, the first trade you won, the 2nd you lost.

At this point, I want the next time the system gives me an entry signal (RSI < 30, entry long), not enter the trade, because the last trade it was a loss.

Comment: So the third trade from the print above would not exist.

The other detail is that I want the strategy to recognize when I would have a hypothetical loss.

Because, if the 3rd trade never existed, you would not have a loss on your capital, BUT if you had opened that order, it would ALSO be a loss, so the goal is to system cancel the 4th trade as well.

The 4th trade was also a hypothetical loss, if it doesn't exist, as I said above, then the 5th trade wouldn't exist either (because last "trade" was a loss) .

Comment: You can check profitability of last trade usgin https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy{dot}closedtrades{dot}profit. If last trade was profitable, place new entry. If not, you writes potential entry price in separate variable and calculates potential loss when condition for exit occurs.